# SQL query for retrive data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

[OPEN THIS SQL PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSmNp.png)

Can somebody help me about this problem? How to write query for that? Click OPEN THIS SQL PROBLEM to view.

Comment: you should learn to do your homework without seeking help

Comment: What's the problem? You didn't show what you tried. Anyway, take a look at `JOIN`. First google result to `mysql join`: [Mysql JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Can you show which solutions you already tried?

Comment: "SELECT customer_ID FROM account WHERE amount=250" and i now need to use this to select from first table... Should I use INNER JOIN?

Comment: I suggest you to read about it. Really, do some research. This should return what's needed: `SELECT C.*, A.* FROM account A INNER JOIN customer C ON A.customer_ID = C.customer_ID WHERE A.amount=250;`. Remember to change `C.*` and `A.*` to the actual field list.

Answer (score 0):

Select customer.name from customer
Left join account 
On customer.customer_id = account.customer_id 
Where account.amount=250